# JavaFX MouseDragReleased event not being sent to target node in fullDrag

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to implement a Chess Game. The board GUI is a gridPane of stackPanes (Square class). the pieces are imageViews on the stackPanes. When a drag is detected on a piece it starts a full drag. when the drag is released it is supposed to send a mouseDragReleased event to the stackPane under the mouse at the release point. But instead the event is sent to the original stackPane where the piece started. I have looked everywhere and can't find a solution. Where is the bug?

```
public class Square extends StackPane {

    private final int rank;
    private final char file;

    public Square(int colorType, int rank, char file) {
        super();

        Color color;
        if (colorType == 0)
            color = Color.DARKGREEN;
        else 
            color = Color.BEIGE;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.file = file;

        this.setPrefSize(60, 60);
        this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(color, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        this.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(1))));
        setMouseEventHandlers();
    }

    public void initializePieceImage(ChessPiece piece) {
        if (piece != null) {
            PieceImageView pieceImageView = new PieceImageView(piece.getColor(), SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(piece.getImage(), null), piece.getRank(), piece.getFile());
            this.getChildren().clear();
            this.getChildren().add(pieceImageView);
        }
    }

    private void setMouseEventHandlers() {

        this.setOnMouseDragReleased(((MouseDragEvent event) -> {  
            PieceImageView newPieceImageView = (PieceImageView) event.getGestureSource();
            if (ChessGame.movePiece(newPieceImageView.getRank(), newPieceImageView.getFile(), this.getRank(), this.getFile())) { // move legality check
                this.getChildren().clear(); 
                newPieceImageView.setFile(this.getFile());
                newPieceImageView.setRank(this.getRank());
                Square oldSquare = (Square) newPieceImageView.getParent();
                this.getChildren().add(newPieceImageView);  
                }
        }));
    }
```

```
public class PieceImageView extends ImageView {

    private final PlayerColor color;
    private int rank;
    private char file;
    private double startDragX;
    private double startDragY;

    public PieceImageView(PlayerColor color, Image image, int rank, char file) {
        super(image);
        this.color = color;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.file = file;
        if (color.equals(ChessGame.getPlayerColor()))
            setMouseEventHandlers();
    }

    private void setMouseEventHandlers() {
        this.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
            this.setMouseTransparent(true);
        });

        this.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent event) -> {
            this.setMouseTransparent(false);
        });

        this.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            startDragX = event.getSceneX();
            startDragY = event.getSceneY();
            this.getParent().toFront();
            this.startFullDrag();

        });

        this.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
            this.setTranslateX(event.getSceneX() - startDragX);
            this.setTranslateY(event.getSceneY() - startDragY);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a complete example that demonstrates the problem (e.g. just use a circle as the "image" for the piece, have one piece the user can move around a board, etc.), include the application class etc in your post? (It's pretty difficult to help debug this without running it.) Are you certain it's calling the drag released handler on the source square (e.g. are you logging the rank and file in the handler)? It seems like you are never resetting the `translateX` and `translateY` of the piece, so maybe that's why it ends up in the wrong place?

Comment: @James_D when I add System.out.println("" + this.rank + this.file) in the setOnMouseDragReleased method it prints the rank and file of the original square that the piece was on and not of the square over which the mouse drag was released.

Comment: @James_D what do you mean by resetting the translateX and translateY?

Comment: When the piece is dragged, you set its translateX and translateY. You never reset it to zero when the piece is dropped, so it will be translated in its new parent. (But obviously you need to figure out the other issue as well.)

Comment: @James_D thanks, I fixed that and now the piece snaps back to the original square showing that the other problem still exits - namely that the mouseDragReleased event is being handled by the original square and not the one under the cursor at release.

Comment: @James_D I figured out the issue - I call toFront on the pieceImage's parent square at the start of the drag so all events on the gridpane are sent to it. how do I ensure that whatever square that is under the mouse is at the front of the gridPane group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding this line to the Square constructor:

```
this.setPickOnBounds(false);
```